# Adjust `this` context of methods in object passed as a function argument

Tags: typescript, types, casting, typescript-generics

I've got a problem with updating the `this` context to methods of object passed as an argument.

```
function decorate<T extends {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (this: infer This, ...args: infer Args) => infer Return
        ? (this: This & { abc: 10 }, ...args: Args) => Return
        : never;
}>(object: T) {
    // @ts-ignore: just a hack to show a simple example
    object.abc = 10;
    return object;
}

decorate({
   getString() { return "abc"; },
   doSomething() {
       const str: string = this.getString(); // Property 'getString' does not exist on type '{ abc: 10; }'.(2339)
       const abc: number = this.abc;
   }
});
```

TypeScript detected `abc` correctly, but lost access to original context. Digging deeper, it looks that inferred `This` is `unknown`:

```
function decorate<T extends {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (this: infer This, ...args: infer Args) => infer Return
        ? (this: This, ...args: Args) => Return
        : never;
}>(object: T) {
    // @ts-ignore: just a hack to show a simple example
    object.abc = 10;
    return object;
}

decorate({
   getString() { return "abc"; },
   doSomething() {
       const str: string = this.getString(); // Object is of type 'unknown'. (2571)
       const abc: number = this.abc; // Object is of type 'unknown'. (2571)
   }
});
```

I tried to use directly the original object as a context, but the `T` at this point is detected only as an object (`{}`), with unknown properties:

```
function decorate<T extends {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: infer Args) => infer Return
        ? (this: T, ...args: Args) => Return
        : never;
}>(object: T) {
    // @ts-ignore: just a hack to show a simple example
    object.abc = 10;
    return object;
}

decorate({
   getString() { return "abc"; },
   doSomething() {
       const str: string = this.getString(); // Property 'getString' does not exist on type '{}'. (2339)
       const abc: number = this.abc; // Property 'abc' does not exist on type '{}'. (2339)
   }
});
```

Is there a way to adjust the context of methods of passed object, or maybe there is completely different way to achieve similar effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to use `ThisType`. This is a special marker interface for the compiler that allows you to easily specify what `this` should mean. When you assign an object to a location typed as `ThisType<T>`, `T` is considered to be the type of `this` for any method/function defined with-in that object.

With this, the solution to your problem becomes very simple:

```
function decorate<T>(object: T & ThisType<T & { abc: number }>) {
    return Object.assign( object, { abc:  10 });
}

decorate({
   getString() { return "abc"; },
   doSomething() {
       const str: string = this.getString(); // Property 'getString' does not exist on type '{}'. (2339)
       const abc: number = this.abc; // Property 'abc' does not exist on type '{}'. (2339)
   }
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKYTgJwIZVQHgBUA+ACjgCMArdKALkUMQDJGALGAZ0IE8AHAk1YBvRNgoQGYEAFsKqTIgC+xAJSJhAWABQiPYkyooITEgDy1WgDpsnTjADmYUoko1oAGg1iJDRAEYABmVVAG4dJR0dNAwcPFItXT0HIwBlKEwYMAdSdVFDY1NEACJxCGLQ5Q8dfWQ4VLgZIw5s3I0a-X0MME4oRF7MBgGsh0QAXkQoDk4rFKh0zNawxAB6FcQABUw4AUwoHkQAcjmFkcOUOFRORDA4PtQADy4+hEn+VCPhJUOrRFIAJgAzICAJyqDqdRDdXo+SQ3WTyRQTKZcGwSSprTbbXb7I5lc51K43O6IR7PVxIfYCT7fX4A4FgiGRbRKMJAA)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `ThisType` marker, it worked like a charm!